# How to stop Python 2.7 running when "python3" is called in terminal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, environment

When I run python3 in terminal, it states that I am running Python 2.7.10. I updated a pip package and conda package and since I have no way of running python3. I am sure python 2 is running as writing 'print "hello"' works which is should not, if python3 successfully ran.

```
Daves-MBP:Desktop dave$ python3

Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct  6 2017, 22:29:07) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.31)] on darwin

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print "hello"
hello
```

This should NOT work if python3 is running. 
How can I get python3 running when I want to? 
Do I need to set up the environment path, or something else?

Comment: what happens when running just `python`??

Comment: maybe you have an alias linking python3 to python2 path

Comment: When typing "python" the same 2.7 version runs

Comment: @Chris_Rands how could I go about correcting that? My python runs from the anaconda2 location at the moment. I have about 6 locations where python is installed (i.e. in anaconda2&3 etc). Do you know the command which returns the list of usr/bin etc locations where python is installed ? Thanks

Comment: Run `which python3` and see where it's pointed to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news. I have solved the problem myself (using a different forum article) 
Setting the alias to the different python version in terminal solves this error.

```
$ alias python='python3.7'
$ alias python2='python2'
$ alias python3='python3.7'
```

So when I type 'python' in terminal, python3 is called. Not sure if my issue was an alias or path issue, as I was not aware of both concepts before I had the problem.

Make sure you have the python version installed before typing in python3.7 or 3.5 for instance.

Also, python3 alone does not work.
Type python3.1 or python3.3